# $routeParams Empty on $locationChangeSuccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I configure my app in the following run block. Basically I want to preform an action that requires me to know the `$routeParams` every `$locationChangeSuccess`.

**However `$routeParams` is empty at this point!** Are there any work rounds? What's going on?

```
app.run(['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {

    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function () {
        console.log($routeParams);
    });

}]);
```

**UPDATE**

```
function configureApp(app, user) {

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/rentroll', {
                templateUrl: 'rent-roll/rent-roll.html',
                controller: 'pwRentRollCtrl'
            }).

            when('/bill', {
                templateUrl: 'bill/bill/bill.html',
                controller: 'pwBillCtrl'
            }).

            when('/fileroom', {
                templateUrl: 'file-room/file-room/file-room.html',
                controller: 'pwFileRoomCtrl'
            }).

            when('/estate-creator', {
                templateUrl: 'estate/creator.html'
            }).

            when('/estate-manager', {
                templateUrl: 'estate/manager.html',
                controller: 'pwEstateManagerCtrl'
            }).

            when('/welcomepage', {
                templateURL: 'welcome-page/welcome-page.html',
                controller: 'welcomePageCtrl'
            }).

            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/welcomepage'
            });
    }]);

    app.run(['$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'pwCurrentEstate','pwToolbar', function ($rootScope, $routeParams, pwCurrentEstate, pwToolbar) {

        $rootScope.user = user;



        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function () {
            pwToolbar.reset();
            console.log($routeParams);
        });

    }]);

}
```

Accessing URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/landlord/#/rentroll?landlord-account-id=ahlwcm9wZXJ0eS1tYW5hZ2VtZW50LXN1aXRlchwLEg9MYW5kbG9yZEFjY291bnQYgICAgICAgAoM&billing-month=2014-06
```

Comment: Show us the $routeProvider configuration and what URL do you access that give you empty $routeParams.

Comment: Updated with what you asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this worked for me, inside your run callback:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $routeParams, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function() {
   var params = $location.search();
   console.log(params);
   console.log('landlord-account-id:', params['landlord-account-id']);
   console.log('billing-month', params['billing-month']);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

By accessing `/rentroll` you will get empty `$routeParams` because your `$routeProvider`
configuration for that path is not expecting any variable on URL.

`$routeParams` is used for getting variable value of your URL. For example :

```
$routeProvider
.when('/rentroll/:variable', {...});
```

and access it on `/rentroll/something` will give you `$routeParams` as below :

```
$routeParams.variable == 'something';
```

Comment: I am confused. I am talking about query params, key=value following the '?'. How do I get those?

Comment: For that case, what you need is $location.search();

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Explains a bit about when the $routeParams are available and why.

To solution here might be to use `$route.current.params`